# How to determine winning auction prices for ads served to me?

Tags: javascript, browser, ads, prebid.js

With personal data mining in the news, monetization of this data and ultimately the valuation that Facebook, Google and others enjoy, derives from showing ads.

I have what should be a pretty simple question-

How much are advertisers actually paying to show me an ad? What's the winning price in each auction run for me?

Prior art, there was a project called YourValue:

https://team.inria.fr/privatics/yourvalue/

http://privatics.inrialpes.fr/~lukasz/rtbdesc.html

http://privatics.inrialpes.fr/~lukasz/rtbdesc2.html

It was able to extract pricing on some sites, and had a Firefox and Chrome plugin:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rtbwatcher/

Unfortunately it had very little adoption, and the project as a whole has now been dead for several years. It's unclear if the price detection machinery is still valid.

In the realm of current work, header bidding and prebid.js can shed light on pricing:

http://prebid.org/dev-docs/toubleshooting-tips.html#see-all-bids-in-the-console

But very few sites are using prebid.

What's a programmatic way I figure out what my eyeballs are worth to advertisers across different sites?

Answer (score 2):

I think *header bidding* is the most important advancement in ad tech since the introduction of real-time bidding (RTB).

The main reason for saying it is:

> Header bidding is an additional auction that takes place outside of
>   the ad server, in the header of a web page, which loads before
>   anything else on the page. The header typically contains metadata
>   about the page and calls scripts used for formatting the style of the
>   page, tracking, and so on. Because of this, it’s an ideal area to
>   conduct a new auction.

Image below shows information about percentage of client side tools for header bidding:

[image]

**Client side Header Bidding**

You can choice a most used tools like *Criteo* but it's not free.

**S2S Header Bidding**

It's true that only about **12 percent** of the Alexa top 1,000 websites — 121 sites — are using client side header bidding.

The Problems with Client-Side Header Bidding is (for more info please see my [reference](https://www.adpushup.com/blog/server-to-server-header-bidding-everything-you-need-to-know/)):

1. Browser request limitations
2. High ad and page latency
3. Limiting response times
4. Auction discrepancies
5. Negative UX impact

As a result, many sites use [S2S header bidding](http://digitaladblog.com/2017/05/07/4-server-server-s2s-header-bidding-trends/).

S2S header bidding works in pretty much the same way as client-side except for one change: Instead of the user’s browser, the auction now happens outside on a server provided by a technology partner.

Only one code needs to be inserted in the header now to communicate with the server instead of one code for every demand partner. This small change makes a big difference, let’s see how in the next section.

In conclusion, you can use S2S header bidding for doing it better.

Comment: Thanks @alisoltani. I agree about the importance of header bidding and understand and agree about the difference between its instantiation client vs server side from a site operator perspective. In the context of the question, however, I am not a site operator. I am a user. I want to know how much my eyeballs are worth. Sites doing client side header bidding often expose that information to the client. I want a pricing transparency solution when visiting sites that do s2s or traditional adserving. So- I'm afraid that this post does not answer that question.

Answer (score 2):

> prebid.js can shed light on pricing

I think this is your best bet!

Facebook aside, GAM / Google Ad Manager (formerly Doubleclick For Publishers) is responsible for serving the lion's share of ads, but the clientside library that facilitates this is GPT / `googletag`, doesn't expose the value of impressions sold.

As such, peeking at offers that Prebid networks make on impressions gives you access to a sample of indicative values of the impressions on the current site, from your location, etc.

Prebid header-bidding is a first-price auction, so the highest Prebid bid is sent to GAM, which then conducts a second-price auction, and auctions are conducted in CPM, which stands for Cost Per Mille, or cost per thousand impressions.

So if, for a single impression:

- Appnexus bids 0.50
- Rubicon bids 0.61

via prebid, then a winning bid of 0.61 is sent to GAM. If

- Google Ad Exchange then bids 0.90

...they'll actually pay just enough to beat the second price, so: $0.62 per 1000 impressions = $0.00062.

There are so many shortcomings with this... we're skipping over a bunch of complexities like price granularity, discrepancies, and especially the fact that this is what the publisher was paid (excluding possible revshare agreements with networks), not what the advertiser spent! Still... it's indicative!

There's a great Chrome extension for monitoring auctions: [AdWizard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adwizard/kndnhcfdajkaickocacghchhpieogbjh?hl=nl&q=HTML5-ifier), which demonstrates how you can listen for prebid events such as `bidWon` and googletag's event `slotRenderEnded` and combine the data to establish whether Prebid won the auction, and what the winning CPM was.

You could examine the source and use the very same listeners in your own browser extension to post this data to your logging server, so that you can aggregate data about your browsing later...

[image: AdWizard showing an auction for a single impression]

Answer (score 0):

Google AdMob provides publishers with an ad dashboard where you may get more details about ads. Going to the 'ad unit performance' option of the Google AdMob app overview dashboard will provide you access to:

Top performers: When you choose top performers from the drop-down option, the card displays your top-performing ad units for the given time and their expected revenues. A period-to-period comparison gets included as well.

Top and bottom movers: When you choose top & bottom movers from the drop-down option, the card displays the ad units with the most change in expected revenues during the given time. A period-to-period comparison will also get included.

If you are working with an ad mediation provider and want to know more about your ad units and their performance, you may ask for this specific metric to be included in your reports.

Answer (score -1):

Adblock has an API you can use to run reports against your own browsing history, device usage, ads blocked, etc. One could use this API to compile a variety of reports on which specific ads, types of ads, producers of ads, and brands served in the ads would have passed by your eyeballs. From there, you could potentially devise a method to track the CPM, Page Impressions, etc and cost per each to estimate and project your value to advertisers and/or big data retailers.

Adblock API: https://www.adblockanalytics.com/api/

Comment: Thanks @dshiz. I would love for this to be the case, but as far as I can tell, adblockanalytics reports are only for site operators and customers of their service. As a user, I want to understand my value across sites I visit, not sites I operate. I don't see a way that adblockanalytics can provide that to me. I'm afraid this post does not answer the question.